# r shiny how to combine data table proxy and bs modal

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, shinybs

I would like to display selected items from a table. The table is displayed via bsModal. And the selection of the table is done via dataTableProxy.
I would also like to be able to select certain items via a button.

Problem: If I start the app and click on the "add" button, nothing happens. I have to open the Modal first (I don't have to select anything) for the button to work. Only once the modal has been opened once, I can use the button.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("search", "Search for Items"),
  actionButton("add_items", "Add Items"),
  DTOutput("selection"),
  
  bsModal("modal", "DT", "search", DTOutput("data"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$data <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris)
  })
  
  shortlist_dt <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$data_rows_selected)){return()}
    datatable(iris %>% slice(input$data_rows_selected))
    })
  
  output$selection <- renderDT(shortlist_dt())
  
  proxy_data = dataTableProxy('data')
  
  observeEvent(input$add_items, {
    proxy_data %>% selectRows(c(input$data_rows_selected, 2, 3))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that the `data` output object is not yet rendered when the app is initialized. The moment when you open the modal is the moment when the output is indeed materialized.

Possible solutions:

- (Applied) conditionalPanel for the insert button so sb has to start with the search step
- Java Script code to open and close the modal when the app is started
- Redesign the app
- ...

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$span(  
    style = "display: flex",
    actionButton("search", "Search for Items"),
    conditionalPanel("output.data", actionButton("add_items", "Add Items"))
  ),
  DTOutput("selection"),
  bsModal("modal", "DT", "search", DTOutput("data"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$data <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris)
  })
  
  shortlist_dt <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$data_rows_selected)){return()}
    datatable(iris %>% slice(input$data_rows_selected))
  })
  
  output$selection <- renderDT(shortlist_dt())
  
  proxy_data = dataTableProxy('data')
  
  observeEvent(input$add_items, {
    proxy_data %>% selectRows(c(input$data_rows_selected, 2, 3))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

EDIT:

Code for clicking and closing the modal when the app started.

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("search", "Search for Items"),
  actionButton("add_items", "Add Items"),
  DTOutput("selection"),
  bsModal("modal", "DT", "search", DTOutput("data")),
  tags$script("$(document).on('shiny:connected', function() {
                 $('button#search').click();
                 setTimeout(function() {
                   $('div.modal-footer button').click();
                 }, 1000);
               });")
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought about conditional panel, but in most cases users are just using the add button. Do you happen to know how to use JS to open/closes this modal?